# select item with "0" as value in kendo dropdown

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

The datasource for select k-kendo-dropdown grid has two values as follow:
{desc: 'zero', value : '0'}
{desc: 'One', value : '1'}

Even if the k-ng-model has value 0, zero does not get selected.
If I use any other value, then the corresponding desc gets selected.

On googling it , i saw a link that there is an issue with using 0 as value for select kendodropdown.
Someone suggested to use input data-role='dropdown' instead. (http://www.telerik.com/forums/data-value-not-working-when-zero)

but I am looking for a workaround with select kendodropdown.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the drop-down list's data source is something like

```
[
    {"TypeId":0,"TypeName":"???"},
    {"TypeId":1,"TypeName":"PC"},
    ...
]
```

Using `k-ng-model="integerValue"` with `k-value-primitive="true"` can successfully bind the value to the drop down.

[k-value-primitive](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/AngularJS/widget-basics/binding#enabling-k-value-primitive)